# Angular2 - emit http.get from other component

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5

I use AngularJS (1.5) at work and created now my first Angular2 application. Now I have a little problem with observable.

I have a service like this (TicketService):

```
import { Injectable, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Globals } from '../../globals';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class TicketService {

private http;
private emitter: EventEmitter<any>;

constructor (http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
    this.emitter = new EventEmitter();
}

findAll () {
    return this.http.get(Globals.BASE_API_URL + '/ticket');
}

emitEvent(value) {
    this.emitter.emit(this.findAll());
}

getEmit() {
    return this.emitter;
}
```

And I have a component to list all tickets (app-order-page):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TicketService } from '../../ticket/ticket.service';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-order-page',
    templateUrl: './order-page.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./order-page.component.css']
})
export class OrderPageComponent implements OnInit {

    private states;
    private ticketService: TicketService;
    private tickets;
    private isPreview;

    constructor (ticketService: TicketService) {
        this.ticketService = ticketService;
    }

    ngOnInit () {            
        this.ticketService.getEmit().subscribe(value => {
            value.subscribe(v => {
                this.tickets = v.json();
            })
        });

        this.ticketService.emitEvent(true);
    }

}
```

Now I want from another component reload the list of tickets in the app-order-page:

```
this.ticketService.emitEvent(true);
```

So, this example works, but its crazy. I have to do a subscribe in a subscribe. Is that a problem? Do I have other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue can be resolved using Subject(instead of Emitter), Observable and switchMap(function of Observable, you can google it on how to use).
See sample code snippet below.

```
findAll (): Observable<any> {
    return this.sampeSubject.switchMap(e => this.http.get(Globals.BASE_API_URL + '/ticket').map(resp => resp.json())); //this would return an Observable
}
reload(){
   this.sampeSubject.next();
}
```

You can then call the **reload** function if you want to reload the list of tickets.